# ZedGraph doesn't print real values

Tags: label, zedgraph

I'm using Zedgraph and I've a problem with values printed beside axis.
When my curve has values between 0 and 1000, no problem. But when I have values between 10 000 and 100 000 for example, Zedgraph prints 10 to 100 instead of 10 000 to 100 000 (or 1e4 to 1e5, I don't care).

Do you know which option can I change to have 10 000 to 100 000 instead of 10 to 100 ?

I've looked on scale.format property, it doesn't work.

One thing mode, when I use the contextmenu option "see values" the values printed near my cursor are good, so it's not a problem of wrong value saved by Zedgraph.

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yAxis.Scale.Mag = 0;
```

See [Zedgraph-Documentation (API)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/files/zedgraph%20documentation/5.1.0%20+%204.6.0/):

> This (Mag) is used to limit the size of the displayed value labels. For example, if the value is really 2000000, then the graph will display 2000 with a 10^3 magnitude multiplier. This value can be determined automatically depending on the state of MagAuto. If this value is set manually by the user, then MagAuto will also be set to false.